# How to create LitElement without Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, lit-element, lit

I am creating a web components using LitElement. This is from https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/start

```
// Import the LitElement base class and html helper function
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

// Extend the LitElement base class
class MyElement extends LitElement {

  /**
   * Implement `render` to define a template for your element.
   *
   * You must provide an implementation of `render` for any element
   * that uses LitElement as a base class.
   */
  render(){
    /**
     * `render` must return a lit-html `TemplateResult`.
     *
     * To create a `TemplateResult`, tag a JavaScript template literal
     * with the `html` helper function:
     */
    return html`
      <!-- template content -->
      <p>A paragraph</p>
    `;
  }
}
// Register the new element with the browser.
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

How to create LitElement without Shadow DOM?

I want to create it without #shadow-root here:
[image]

Comment: Did you try specifying a `renderRoot`? https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/api/classes/_lit_element_.litelement.html#createrenderroot

Comment: `createRenderRoot() { return this;}` solved it!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just to make sure this question is shown as answered:

`createRenderRoot` allows you to override the operation that creates a shadow root. It's usually used to render to light dom:

```js
createRenderRoot() {
  return this;
}
```

Though it could be used to render somewhere else entirely.

I really recommend using shadow DOM. Composition is difficult if an element overwrites its own light DOM.

Comment: How else do you suggest using Bootstrap or other website wide stylesheet?

Comment: Ideally your stylesheets are broken down so that you can import only the parts each component needs. I would wrap those parts in JS modules so that they can be automatically loaded with the components, bundled, etc., then inject them into the shadow roots.

Comment: it appears that shadow roots break focus-visible behavior.. fun

Comment: Note override `createRenderRoot` will make shadow DOM features like encapsulated CSS and slots unavailable. Then what's the meaning to use the web component?

Comment: @TinaChen web component allows you to, well, componentize your code, which is almost always an improvement if you are not already using React/Vue/Angular etc. You still get encapsulation. Also, if you already have a huge code base with a lot of CSS rules, it can be hard to convert the styling to use lit CSS. And there are many other minor issues that make adopting shadow DOM complicated. We are not living in an ideal world.

Comment: If it doesn't have a shadow DOM, it's a custom element, not a web component.

Comment: Are slots only specific to shadow-dom? Can't the light dom use slots too?

Comment: <slot>s are a shadow DOM feature. For a slot concept to work you need a separation between projected content and the spot to project into. That doesn't work with only one context like like DOM w/o shadow DOM.

Comment: @ryanafrish7 you could use bootstrap shadow dom just by linking the bootstrap in your component, the same you do in the normal dom. This will not overload the page, because same link will be cached.

Comment: @TheFool It's always a custom element regardless. Personally I don't use the term "web component" because, well, even a React component is a "web component", which is confusing. Elements (builtin or custom)!

Comment: @trusktr, yes but not the other way around. Web Components is a superset of custom elements. So every web component is a custom element but not every custom element is a web component.